# Setting up phpstorm with xdebug

Tags: xdebug, phpstorm

I have been trying to set up remote (virtual box server) debugging with phpstorm. When I press the debug button phpstorm just waits indefinitely for a connection. I've been looking for a solution for a couple days, and cannot get any varying results.

These are my phpstorm settings:
Host: mywebsite.dev
Port: 9000
Debugger: Xdebug
pathmapping: /public <--> /index.php

These are my xdebug params in php.ini

```
xdebug.remote_enable=on
xdebug.remote_autostart=off
xdebug.remote_handler=dbgp
xdebug.remote_connect_back=on
xdebug.remote_port=9000
xdebug.default_enable=on
xdebug.remote_mode=req
xdebug.remote_log=/var/log/xdebug/xdebug.log
```

Please let me know if you need anymore information. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Refer to [the tutorial](http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Zero-configuration+Web+Application+Debugging+with+Xdebug+and+PhpStorm).

Comment: Even better: Webinar (video!!): http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/07/webinar-recording-debugging-php-with-phpstorm/

Answer (score 0):

This tutorial worked for me in Ubuntu

http://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/PhpStorm/Xdebug+Installation+Guide

I notice your php.ini looks a bit different.  Here is mine :

```
[Xdebug]
zend_extension=<full_path_to_xdebug_extension>
xdebug.remote_enable=1
xdebug.remote_host=<the host where PhpStorm is running (relative to your site!)>
xdebug.remote_port=9000
```

And that was it.

Answer (score 0):

Answering an old post for the heck of it...

You also need to edit you 20-xdebug.ini file
`sudo nano /etc/php5/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini`
The line `zend_extension=xdebug.so` should already be there.  Add the following lines  :

```
    zend_extension=xdebug.so
    xdebug.remote_enable = 1
    xdebug.remote_connect_back = 1
    xdebug.remote_port = 9000
    xdebug.scream=0 
    xdebug.cli_color=1
    xdebug.show_local_vars=1
```

There might be path mapping issues as well.
 If you go in run|web server debug validation … do you get error messages ?  If so, that’s a clue to what you still need to solve.

You also have to set the key to your xdebug extension in your browser.